# Removing application right to use Google account

Tags: java, android, authentication, google-account

I have used AccountManager to handle user login with Google account. Because this software is in development, I need to test it again and again. I'd like to know, how do I remove these rights from an app to reauthenticate it for test purposes?

I've done the authentication as showed in this [Google developers document](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html). It produces an authentication screen like this

[image: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/google-account-integration-in-android-login-with-gmail.html]

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://security.google.com/settings/security and click on "review permissions" next to "Connected sites and applications."

Here you can revoke access to your Google account for third-party sites and apps. You should then be able to re-request access via your app.

Comment: How should I know which one is the correct one? Websites I can see with their domain name, but Android applications show as Android Login Service. Edit. I removed the all and nothing changed.

Comment: Actually, when I removed all those Android Login Services, it removed my login from my phone and tablet, not from the software.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable method that I've found is to remove the Google account from the device and add it again. The next time your app is run, it will show the "This app would like to..." screen again.

I have two Google accounts on each of my test devices and can quickly delete/add the second (less frequently used) one when I'm testing authentication workflows.

Comment: This might work, but I think it's too much work. I bet there's an easier solution.

Comment: If you find one, please share. :)